# Expected value of function in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have the following for loop in python:

```
import numpy as np
data=np.random.normal(shape=[1000,1]) # but I cannot assume the data will always be a known distribution. Arbitrary data will be fed through from some **unknown** distribution.
percentile=.05
interval_slice=1e-6

integral_range = np.arange(start=percentile, stop=0.000001, step=-abs(interval_slice))

result = []

for i in integral_range:
    val = np.percentile(data, q=i)
    result.append(val)

print(np.mean(result))
```

Generally, my question here is to ask if there is a faster way to do this.

I looked into:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_discrete.expect.html
and https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.cumtrapz.html (lol) but neither solves this exact problem.

Generally, I want  a *faster* way to `map` percentile over this range. I assume scipy or numpy has something but I can't seem to find it.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the sample input and expected output? Your code is not reproducible.

Comment: @QuangHoang sorry about that. code is reproducible now.

Comment: @QuangHoang let's assume the `print` is the output.

Comment: `np.percentile(data,integral_range).mean()`?

Comment: You can use list comprehension, or the map function

Comment: @QuangHoang yep that works. it wasn't clear from the docs that it accepted an array.